# Unordered_Map of Maps or Priority_Queues?

Tags: c++, hash, dictionary, priority-queue, unordered-map

I have a struct that consists of a name and an age.  What I would like is to have an unordered_map that takes a strings as its keys and then either a map or a priority_queue that then stores the age given that string:

```
struct Person{
   string name;
   int age;

   bool operator() (const Person &other){}
};    

unordered_map<string,priority_queue<Person,vector<Person>> map;
    or 
unordered_map<string,map<int,Persons>> map;
```

I know I the declarations syntax are entirely correct, but hopefully you get the idea...

Which should I go with for best performance?  The idea is to be able to search, insert, remove very fast.

Comment: Given that you can't search a `std::priority_map<T>` it is not an option! It seems you didn't specify your requirements. A priority queue is only good at one thing: determining the object with the highest priority. Also, why does it matter that the map or the priority queue are within a hash map?

Comment: Well you answer your question by saying you want the fastest. On the [c++ page](cplusplus.com), it gives you runtime of the algorithms used for each implementation

Comment: priority_queue and map both have the same implementation

Comment: That's not true. Yes, they have the same complexity for almost all operations, but map uses balanced trees (like red-black) while priority_queue is an implementation of binary heap on some random access container (like vector<>). You can refer to cplusplusreference.com for details

Comment: meant complexity sorry

Answer (score 1):

priority_queue is a very specific data structure which supports a limited set of operations: get size, get or remove the maximal element, add a new element. So if you need to randomly access and remove your elements, map is the only valid choice of these two options.

In general, both of them work in O(log N). priority_queue is faster but is less powerful. It's faster because it uses heap instead of balanced trees, which results in better memory usage (all elements lies together in the same memory block) and less memory (re)allocations.